# Additional VIP on Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

I have a requirement to run two different websites, each with its own SAN certificate. This requires that we have 2 IP (or VIPs) on the machine. The machine that will run these websites is currently in Azure as a Virtual Machine running Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have contacted Microsoft Azure Billing support and have been granted a total quota of 3 VIPs on my subscription. How do I now add a second VIP to the Virtual Machine. I cannot find an option for it in the Azure management portal, and the powershell commands (get vm, add ip, updatevm) does not seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have 2 VIPs on a single VM.  If you can upgrade your VM to Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8 then you can use SNI to enable HTTPs on multiple domains on one VM.  Otherwise your only option will be to create 2 VMs or use something else like Windows Azure Websites.

Answer (score 0):

While I have not attempted this within Azure, I would imagine it should follow a standard networking model. You could simply place the VIPs on a loopback interface, then explicitly assign those IPs to your desired virtuals within IIS. No virtual should listen on *:443 or *:80. You would then bind your SSL to the desired IP on the virtual, explicitly. This can all be done within IIS. Azure might be different, but that's how I would do it on a standard build sans Azure. Ping me if you have another questions, but I believe this is very do-able within the current technology stack. I don't have extra VIPs to test within my own Azure account, though, so cannot validate my basic assumptions.